# all images got blured in Android

Tags: android, image, imageview, blur

I have the problem, that all images, drawn with canvas or in an ImageView got blured.

Here is an example:

orginal Image:

http://img816.imageshack.us/img816/8681/linestest.png

Image in my Application:

http://img715.imageshack.us/img715/4889/linestestdrawn.png

use the loupe to see the differences.

here is some code:

```
<ImageView
        android:src="@drawable/linestest"
        android:layout_width="50px"
        android:layout_height="50px"
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"></ImageView>
```

i tried .png .bmp and .gif but nothing works.

any suggestions how to solve this Problem? I just want to draw my images exactly. So it is impossible to draw 1px lines.

Comment: If you didn't know, the first image you linked is 50x50, the second is 51x49.

Comment: yea sry i just cut it out from a screenshoot. it is exactly 50x50 in my application. But thanks

Comment: Put the Images in the drawable-hdpi folder. The images got rendered for low-dpi devices in the default folder